# given $I_{n,a}=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+\frac{x^2}{a})^n}$ prove that $I_{n+1,a}=\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_{n,a}$

Tags: calculus, integration

given $I_{n,a}=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+\frac{x^2}{a})^n}$ prove that $I_{n+1,a}=\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_{n,a}$

I assume this is integration by parts, but I haven't been able to show that.

Comment: Are you missing integration ranges? If they're what I think they are, you can solve this e.g. by setting $x=\sqrt{a}\tan t$ and using Beta and Gamma functions.

Comment: it should be from -infinity to infinity though I see no reason why it matters.

Comment: It matters because if these were indefinite integrals the ratio would be a function of $x$ instead of a constant.

Comment: okay, I added the limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right to consider integration by parts. Write $u=(1+x^2/a)^{-n},\,v=x$, so $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}uv=0$ and$$I_n=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty u^\prime vdx=2n\int_{-\infty}^\infty(x^2/a)(1+x^2/a)^{-n-1}dx=2n(I_n-I_{n+1}),$$which rearranges into the desired recursion relation.

Comment: sorry, can't understand your answer

Comment: @integrant I've edited it.

Comment: hmm this seems to be the answer, thanks.